# Admob test ads not showing

Tags: android, admob

This is my first android app and I'm trying to use the admob ads for my app but it is not working despite all that I've done.

This are the codes in my activity related to the ad

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
........

    LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ForViewAd);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
   //i've gotten the test ad id by first setting this as 'abc'
   //and then reading off the logcat
    adView.setAdUnitId("XXXXXXXXX");

    rootLayout.addView(adView, 0);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXX")
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The following is my XML codes

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout   
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     .......

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >


     <com.google.ads.AdView 
                android:id="@+id/ForViewAd"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 /> 
     </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The logcat readouts upon running the app on the emulator is both strange and confusing

```
      09-28 15:28:21.076: E/Trace(968): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
       09-28 15:28:21.120: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(968): Google Play services is missing.
       09-28 15:28:21.140: I/Ads(968): Starting ad request.
       09-28 15:28:21.140: I/Ads(968): 
       Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice ("XXXXXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.
       09-28 15:28:21.200: D/dalvikvm(968): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads326198251.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
       09-28 15:28:21.216: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 3% free 10994K/11271K, paused 19ms+11ms, total 36ms
       09-28 15:28:21.324: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x519 dp.
       09-28 15:28:21.340: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x499 dp.
       09-28 15:28:21.356: D/libEGL(968): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
       09-28 15:28:21.372: D/(968): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb975ff68, tid 968
       09-28 15:28:21.380: D/libEGL(968): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
       09-28 15:28:21.380: D/libEGL(968): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
       09-28 15:28:21.432: W/EGL_emulation(968): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
       09-28 15:28:21.448: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): Enabling debug mode 0
       09-28 15:28:21.476: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb95468e0): name, size, mSize = 1, 1048576, 1048576
       09-28 15:28:21.532: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb953e248): name, size, mSize = 2, 9216, 1057792
       09-28 15:28:21.572: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb954fcb8): name, size, mSize = 4, 36864, 1094656
       09-28 15:28:21.576: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb976f528): name, size, mSize = 5, 16384, 1111040
       09-28 15:28:21.576: D/dalvikvm(968): DexOpt: --- END 'ads326198251.jar' (success) ---
       09-28 15:28:21.576: D/dalvikvm(968): DEX prep  '/data/data/com.example.testapp/cache/ads326198251.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 375ms
       09-28 15:28:21.704: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb954edf8): name, size, mSize = 8, 16384, 1127424
       09-28 15:28:21.704: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb955e380): name, size, mSize = 9, 4096, 1131520
       09-28 15:28:21.776: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 4% free 11181K/11527K, paused 14ms+1ms, total 22ms
       09-28 15:28:21.780: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x519 dp.
       09-28 15:28:21.788: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x499 dp.
       09-28 15:28:22.040: W/Ads(968): Invalid unknown request error: [Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?]
       09-28 15:28:22.048: W/Ads(968): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
       09-28 15:28:22.060: W/Ads(968): Failed to load ad: 1
       09-28 15:38:01.600: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 398K, 5% free 11181K/11719K, paused 10ms+1ms, total 18ms
      09-28 15:38:01.604: D/webviewglue(968): nativeDestroy view: 0xb97947e8
      09-28 15:38:01.608: D/webviewglue(968): nativeDestroy view: 0xb97da500
```

As you can see, there are at least 3 errors shown from the logcat. Firstly, the google play services has been imported to the project. I can see it at the android private libraries folder (but not in the libs folder).

There's also the error that says not enough space but I've set the relativelayout right and left padding as 0sp. so there should be enough space widthwise?

Finally, the error code 1, or "Invalid unknown request error"? I don't understand that one.

Other than the logcat and the fact that the ads are not showing anywhere on the activity, the app ran as per normal without problems.

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

The following are the logcat after what was suggested

```
    09-29 17:31:47.290: D/jdwp(1025): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
    09-29 17:31:47.290: D/dalvikvm(1025): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    09-29 17:31:47.302: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(968): Google Play services is missing.
    09-29 17:31:47.302: I/AndroidRuntime(1025): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
    09-29 17:31:47.318: I/Ads(968): Starting ad request.
    09-29 17:31:47.318: I/Ads(968): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.
    09-29 17:31:47.418: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x519 dp.
    09-29 17:31:47.422: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x499 dp.
    09-29 17:31:47.446: W/EGL_emulation(968): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-29 17:31:47.454: D/OpenGLRenderer(968): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb820e8e0): name, size, mSize = 38, 1048576, 1131520
    09-29 17:31:47.526: I/ActivityManager(324): Displayed com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity: +249ms
    09-29 17:31:47.530: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x519 dp.
    09-29 17:31:47.530: W/Ads(968): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x499 dp.
    09-29 17:31:47.606: W/Ads(968): Invalid unknown request error: [Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?]
    09-29 17:31:47.610: W/Ads(968): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
    09-29 17:31:47.610: W/Ads(968): Failed to load ad: 1
    09-29 17:31:47.622: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 256K, 4% free 11580K/11975K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 15ms
    09-29 17:31:47.622: D/webviewglue(968): nativeDestroy view: 0xb85bfb60
```

Comment: Did the solution provided work?

Comment: Not really. The errors seem to be lessening from before, but the ads are still not showing.

Comment: The exception has to do with the space to show the ad. Check the line "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 340x519 dp."

Comment: I see. Is there anyway to amend the xml layout to accomodate for this difference. I've been using google nexus as the emulator, maybe the limitation has to do with the emulator?

Comment: Does the ad show on an actual device. What happens when you change the emulator's orientation to landscape??

Comment: The ad does not show at all. I haven't try landscape because I've locked my app on the portrait orientation

Comment: Why do you place the ad within the linear layout. Do you have other views in the linear layout? The linear layout ads some padding. Try changing the ad's width to  android:layout_width="wrap_content" and see if that works.

Comment: There are no other views in the linear layout apart from the ad. I've tried changing it to relativelayout, setting width to wrap content in both the linear layout and the ad itself. Nothing works. The error is still the same.

Comment: On clicking on the graphical layout for the xml, it says The following classes could not be found:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Change to android.view.View, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Comment: I have a possibly silly question. Are the values xxx the same in  setadunit(xxx) the same as test device(xxx)?

Comment: You should change com.google.ads.AdView to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView. Also make sure you add the gps meta-data tag and activity declaration. You really should take a look at the official guide link in my answer. Also, xxx is just to mask your Ids. You should replace with the original ids

Comment: I've changed it to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView .. also removed the padding in the relative layout in the xml, but the result is still the same. No ads, but the app loads problem-free otherwise. The logcat is similar as above saying the 'google play services in unavailable' and that there is not enough space for ads. I've tried it in the nexus 10 both portrait and landscape to similar results. I'm at wits end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is issue with smart_banner 
//Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp

BANNER ads works fine,

i solve this like...
remove ads from layout and put in root layout, remove margin of root layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
  <layout>
   </layout>
 //here
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "remove margin of root layout" is worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You havent added the testdevice id correctly, I found your device id in your logs and updated the code.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("5C2521D171291728A381823D5ACC9B8D")
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Next, in your layout file just the below is enough, as your java code is setting the adunitid, testdeviceid and adsize. You can put it in either java code or in the layout file.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
                android:id="@+id/ForViewAd"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Including google's official page for more information https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Just tried your suggested fix. Unfortunately, it seems the similar error still occurs. I've updated the logcat above with your method

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Ranjith's answer, since you're using admob via the google play services, you should modify your layout as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 .......

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

You can follow the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration) on migrating from the old admob to new admob

By the way, in future don't post your correct adunit ids on the internet. I've masked it out

Comment: Sorry about that. I will mask out the adunit id hereon out.